# More than one datasets in R Package

Tags: r, dataset, r-package

I have added two datasets in the package using use_that::use_data() and added the documentation also for both the datasets. But only one data is available after loading the package, if i delete one dataset the other one can be accessed.
Is there any way to add more than one datasets in one package , Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have the package somewhere we could see it, e.g., GitHub?

Comment: Did you give them different names? It's not very clear what exactly is happening. A package should have no problem providing multiple datasets. We would need to see some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see what's going on.

Comment: Package is not on gitHub, i am testing. I have given different names. I can add here the data documentation and screenshots